# Why do we have so few Percy Jackson questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

[percy-jackson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/percy-jackson): 12 questions

For comparison, [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) is beyond 2,000.

Percy Jackson seems to be a pretty popular series with a decently large universe.

- Why do we have so few questions on it?
- Is there anything that can be done to entice more (which I feel needs the "why" answered first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Book Popularity

The Harry Potter series of books have been accessed over a billion times (80-100M physical sales of each book + 200M digital sales and at least  50M illegal downloads).

By comparison, the Percy Jackson series appears to have sold less than 20M copies per novel.

That alone should explain the relative lack of interest.

### Film Popularity

On top of that, the HP films are the [single most successful film series of all time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films#Highest-grossing_franchises_and_film_series) (with an average cinematic take of over a billion dollars per film) as compared to Percy Jackson's relatively flaccid $100M per film.

### Target Demographic

The New Yorker also spoke to the book series' young readership and (almost insultingly) simplistic plotlines, neither of which would seem to lend themselves well to providing a good source of questions on a site largely geared towards adults (or at least those aged 13+):

> That slangy, casual style is a hallmark of the Percy Jackson books,
>   which often read like a faithful transcription of teen uptalk. At the
>   level of language, Riordan’s books make J. K. Rowling’s “Harry Potter”
>   series seem as if it were written by Samuel Johnson. **Unlike the Harry
>   Potter books, which, notoriously, have been embraced by adult readers
>   as well as juvenile ones, the Percy Jackson books seem positively
>   contrived to repel adult readers, so thoroughgoing is their
>   affectation of teen goofiness.**

Comment: Not to mention the disparity between the successes of the movie franchises.

Comment: IMHO: Many of the questions in the HP series are questions barely worthy of being asked, let alone answered. Many of them are based on loopholes, unanswered issues and in many cases the unintentional (or intentional) omissions by the author. That there are so many questions should not surprise anyone, there are as many inconsistencies as there are plot threads woven through the series. This does not mean it wasn't good or that I didn't enjoy it. But I suspect much of the attention it gets is less than warranted and does not necessarily indicate a quality product...

Answer (score -3):

<strike>Excluding the latest film, the series predates this site.</strike>  Popular works that aren't contemporaries garner far less activity on this site.  Admittedly, this isn't consistent (super-massive franchises tend to have no problem garnering questions), but it's a trend I've noticed.  [lost](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost) has 13 questions, despite being one of the biggest sci-fi shows of the past decade.  [battlestar-galactica-2004](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica-2004) has a respectable showing with 105.  [alien-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alien-franchise) has 72 questions to its name.  [douglas-adams](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/douglas-adams) (not sure if there's another good 1 tag that shows interest in his works) has a mere 19 questions. [wheel-of-time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wheel-of-time) has 93 questions, despite being one of the largest fantasy book franchises (only its final book was published after the site started).

Meanwhile works that have been going on while the site's around are a bit more prolific; [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) has almost 500 questions.  [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) manages a decent 214 questions.

Undermining this is the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* franchise.  The older [avatar-the-last-airbender](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender) has roughly the same number of questions (~100) as [the-legend-of-korra](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-legend-of-korra) (started in 2012, ended in 2014).

Essentially, my guess is that *current* interest in a work is necessary to result in many questions.  Once there are questions, then there's more activity, and things snowball from there.  To a certain extent, one person can jump-start this, but there's only so far you can get with a bunch of either self-answered or unanswered posts.  Something needs to happen to trigger broad interest to make the number of posts on the tag increase without an individual or small group driving it.  I'm not sure there's any silver bullet fix here.

Sidenote: I'm way more active in TV/film than books.  If someone can suggest popular book series from the past decade or two, we can add more data points.

Comment: Films and books with a rich "world" seem to engender far more questions.

Comment: Except, Percy Jackson **is more of an ongoing franchise** as far as site lifetime, since [the sequel series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heroes_of_Olympus) finished publishing in 2014. By your own logic, Percy Jackson should have had more questions than Harry Potter (where the very last book was IIRC published before the site opened, although the films were ongoing)

Comment: @DVK Ugh, my quick search didn't reveal the sequel series.  Bah!

Comment: @Richard I haven't read it, but doesn't *Wheel of Time* have a rich world?

Comment: @Keen - I haven't read it either. That may be your answer right there...

Comment: @Keen Extremely. Even more so than *Lord of the Rings* IMO, which is saying something. I've always been disappointed in the low popularity of WoT on this site. Maybe that should be another meta qn like this one...